# craft.request.getQuery returns empty on multi lingual site

Tags: queries, language

I have the strangest bug. I have a site with two languages, Norwegian and English. In my code i check for `craft.request.getQuery('prodid')`. Locally in Apache this works fine with both language URLs, but in production on Nginx, it only works on the Norwegian version (the main language).

The URLS looks like this

- http://onepark.no/leie-parkering/paleet?prodid=1
- http://onepark.no/en/rent-parking/paleet?prodid=1

For the english URL (the second) `craft.request.getQuery('prodid')` returns an empty string. For the Norwegian URL it returns "1".

Nginx rewrite code:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

location /en/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
  }

location @enrewrites {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1? last;
  }

location @rewrites {
rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Can you share/double check your nginx conf file?  My guess is that your rewrite rule is dropping all querystrings in the URL.

Comment: You were right, I'm not a server guy myself but noticed a question mark that was out of place, removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the Nginx config as Brad suggested. There was a question mark behind the `p=$1`. When we removed the `?` and restarted PHP it worked.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

location /en/ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ @enrewrites;
  }

location @enrewrites {
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ /en/index.php?p=$1 last;
  }

location @rewrites {
rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```